# C++ timer, windows forms, start on button click

Tags: c++, windows, forms, button, timer

I need your help. I am trying to build an application in C++ using windows forms also, in Visual Studio 2010. The application will be a little more complex, but right now the problem I am stuck on is how to start a timer, that I dragged and dropped on the windows form, at the click of a normal button called "Start", for some reasons for example, timer1.Start() timer1.Stop() or instead of . , -> does not work, I get the error to have a class or something else at the left of Start and Stop. Also I don't know why my timer ticks once, I do initialize Seconds to 1 but if this can also be avoided so it will stay at 0:0 would be great. Thank you ! I just put the relevant code, I have other things like text boxes etc. I managed to make one text box to take only numbers but when I try the same code on another text box to take only numbers my "design" panel won't show me the windows form anymore and gets an error, this would be another problem great to solve. So, button1_Click()...

```
   //
    // timer1
    //
    this->timer1->Enabled = true;
    this->timer1->Interval = 1000;
    this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::timer1_Tick);
    //
    // Time
    //
    this->Time->AutoSize = true;
    this->Time->Enabled = false;
    this->Time->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
    static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
    this->Time->Location = System::Drawing::Point(121, 24);
    this->Time->Name = L"Time";
    this->Time->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 24);
    this->Time->TabIndex = 0;
    this->Time->Text = L"0:0";
    this->Time->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Time_Click);


    #pragma endregion
    private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


    Second = 0;
    Minute = 0;

    //to be executed on pressing the Start Button

    Second++;

    if (Second == 60)
    {
    Second = 0;
    Minute++;
    }
    Sec = Convert::ToString(Second);
    Min = Convert::ToString(Minute);
    Time ->Text = Min + ":" + Sec;

    std::string afisaj = "You have reached elapsed time";
    std::string info = "Paused";

    //std::string afisaj;
                    //std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
                    //std::getline (std::cin,afisaj);
                    //std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

           //std::string info;
                    //std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
                    //std::getline (std::cin,info);
                    //std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

    if ((Minute == 1) && (Second == 35))
    //MessageBox(NULL,"You have reached elapsed time","Paused",MB_OK);
       MessageBox::Show( "You have reached elapsed time", "Paused",MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation );

    }


private: System::Void textBox1_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e)
{

    if(e->KeyChar == '.')
{
        if( this->textBox1->Text->Contains(".") && !this->textBox1->SelectedText->Contains(".") )
            e->Handled = true;  
    }
    // Allow negative numbers
    else if(e->KeyChar == '-' && !(this->textBox1->Text->Contains("-"))){
        e->Handled = true;
        textBox1->Text = "-" + textBox1->Text;
    }
    // Accept only digits ".", "-" and the Backspace character
    else if(!Char::IsDigit(e->KeyChar)&& e->KeyChar != 0x08){
        e->Handled = true;
    }

}
private: System::Void Time_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
}

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    button1->Visible = false;
    timer1->Start();//when u click on button -> timer start
}
       int n = 0; int i = 1;
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this->BackgroundImage = imageList1->Images[n];
    if (n == 2) {
        i = -1;
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        i = 1;
    }
    n += i;

}
```